# Setup Jenkins on VSO with TFS

Tags: tfs, jenkins, azure-devops

Has anyone successfully set up VSO & Jenkins & TFS?

Server URL: `https://<myproject>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`

Login name and user password (using alternative credentials)

What domain name did you use?  `<domain>\username`

If I run the tf command in Command Prompt, it succeeds, but Jenkins shows the same command as failing. I'm lost as to how to debug this. I also tried setting cached credentials for TFS, and not caching them. It seems as though Jenkins does not have cached credentials, but my command prompt does? Why would my system have stored credentials for me, but not Jenkins?

Error from Jenkins: `TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://windwardstudios.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of [version 4.0.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases/tag/tfs-4.0.0) of the [Jenkins Team Foundation Server plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin), Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) from Visual Studio Online (VSO) is now officially supported and both Personal Access Tokens (PAT) & alternate credentials can be used.

See the section [User name and password](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#user-name-and-password) in the wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer, but may not be what you want to hear. This used to work for us about a year ago. It required someone to stay logged into VisualStudio.com with his MSDN credentials on the build server. Then we simply didn't use credentials in the Jenkins TFS plug-in. Then one day, that simply stopped working. We tried alternative credentials, as @MrHinsh suggested, but never got it to work. Eventually we gave up and switched all of our TFS repositories to git (but still hosted on VisualStudio.com). That **does** work with the alternate credentials, and we have been very pleased since.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Jenkins yo use the alternate credentials. It will not work with any other configuration and the credentials are never stored. Every command that you pass must include the same creds.